# Почему RegExp test() не срабатывает для строки, похожей на IPv6?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Вот такой простенький пример:

```js
var a = new RegExp('/[301:42df:240b:ecde:4b05:e3f2:ad73:cd34]:81');
testinput(a, 'http://[301:42df:240b:ecde:4b05:e3f2:ad73:cd34]:81/');

function testinput(re, str) {
  var midstring;
  if (re.test(str)) {
    midstring = ' содержит ';
  } else {
    midstring = ' не содержит ';
  }
  console.log(str + midstring + re.source);
  //WScript.echo(str + midstring + re.source);
}
```

Предполагается, что будет выведено такое сообщение:

```
http://[301:42df:240b:ecde:4b05:e3f2:ad73:cd34]:81/ содержит /[301:42df:240b:ecde:4b05:e3f2:ad73:cd34]:81
```

Но выводится "не содержит". Почему? Как поправить, чтобы срабатывало правильно?

Comment: Вы проверяете на наличие конкретной строки, а не шаблона. Так используйте `indexOf`. `if (str.indexOf('/[301:42df:240b:ecde:4b05:e3f2:ad73:cd34]:81') > -1)` ....

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, спасибо! Переписал с использованием indexOf - работает так, как нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема, видимо, в неправильном шаблоне регулярного выражения.
Переписал с использованием indexOf - это проще и работает так, как нужно.